# Solution for deleting by "name"

Tags: python, django

I need solution for deleting Profesor by his 'name':

```
class Profesor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    suername = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

Imagine is to ask user on html page to input 'name' of Profesor that he want to delete
And then in views.py to delete Profesor by that 'ime'
How can i do that?

I try to create form where i get 'name':

```
class getName(forms.Form):
    name = forms.IntegerField()
```

And then i views.py:

```
def obrisiProfesora(request):
    form = getName()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = getName(requst.POST)
        form.save()
        context = {'form':form}
    profesor = Profesor.objects.filter(name=form.name)

    return render(request, 'brisanje_profesora.html', context)
```

But i dont know how to contionue this

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you'd have e.g. a HTML page with a form, or a view to handle that form..?

Comment: (By the way: why are all of the fields nullable? Would there be anonymous professors? Also, why `suername` [sic], if you already have a foreign key to an user which presumably has an username?)

Comment: now you can look at views.py and forms.py

Answer (score 0):

- Class names are idiomatically `PascalCase` in Python, so `getName` would be `GetName`. However, `NameForm` might be more apt, since that's what it is, a form for a name.
- Similarly, functions are idiomatically `snake_case`.
- Why would the name field be an integer field, when the `name` field in the model is a `CharField`?
- `form.save()` isn't a thing for forms that aren't modelforms. That being said, I don't think you've tried that code very hard, since it'd crash at `requst` not being a thing, nor `context` having been defined.

All in all, with a plain function view you might want something like

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)


def delete_professor(request):
    form = NameForm(data=(request.POST if request.method == "POST" else None))
    if form.is_bound and form.is_valid():
        professor = Profesor.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data["name"])
        professor.delete()   
    return render(request, 'brisanje_profesora.html', context)
```

or with [a class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) (so you don't need to do so much work yourself),

```
class DeleteProfessorView(FormView):
    form_class = NameForm
    template_name = 'brisanje_profesora.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        professor = Profesor.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data["name"])
        professor.delete()
```

Some error handling is elided from both solutions.